# Can Google Play Games service be used for non games

Tags: android, google-play-games

Ok this sounds weird. Google play games was made for games. And it is excellent. Achievements, cloud save, etc.

Now my app is NOT a game. But it is well documented and researched that turning chores/work/etc into games, makes them more fun, and people more likely to want to do them.

And this is what I want to do for my app.  I cant add it to the games section, as it is a productivity/utility app.  Yet I would like to add achievements,etc to it.  And seeing as Google Play Games services already has some of the functionality i need, i thought i could use it.  However, it seems that your app must be a game to use it.

Any one know if you can actually use the services with non games?

Comment: I see that google play services section is available in our non-game app developer console. So why do you think it is not possible?

Comment: I kinda did it, just released an ear training app for musicians that uses Google Play Games services.

Comment: I am just starting out my business. So i havent created a dev account(still sorting stuff out with the bank), so I cant check it out yet. thanks for the info though

Comment: @MaNTiS Did you get any problems or notice from Google so far using it on a non-game? I'm actually planning to use the Play game service for my Personal assistant & yours was the only use case I was able to find!

Comment: Stuff changed, so that I did not finish that project.
But I am pretty sure that it is fine, as a few of the AutoApps applications(tasker plugins), use it, and there is no problem for them. Like stated previously, just make sure that you follow the guidelines(dont want your app to be pulled for some silly reason)

Answer (score 3):

It's technically possible but in circumstances where you are using the services in an app, be careful because if your app doesn't meet the branding requirements, it can be pulled from the Play store as described in the [Google Play Games Services terms of service](https://developers.google.com/games/services/terms).

So long as you can follow the [Google Play Games Services Branding Guidelines](https://developers.google.com/games/services/branding-guidelines) you should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can. The Google staff speaking in [an event yesterday](http://www.eventbrite.co.uk/e/learncampus-make-your-android-app-succeed-on-google-play-tickets-17335980384) in the Google Campus London actually said this.

Answer (score 0):

For examples of already existing popular such apps, checkout Memrise which is a gamified way to learn languages. It sits in "Education" App category and it has leaderboards and achievements in it, though not sure if its GPG or their own implementation of it.