# Is it senseful and legal to use Google Play Game Services for Non-Game-Apps?

Tags: android, google-oauth, google-play-games

**Is it senseful and legal to use Google Play Game Services for anything else than a game?**

I think an app that can upload images could have leaderboards (weekly likes) and achievements. Or a language learning app could also use these features to make the learning process more fun.

Why are there no apps using these features? Is it not allowed? Or is the problem, that the app would be listed as a game in the Play Store, even if it is not a game? Will Google ban such apps?

Comment: yes it is entirely legal you can gamify any app. I'm sure there are examples of this, would just need to find them :-)

Comment: I've searched a lot and didn't find a single example. Also I have no source, for if it is legal or not. Until now I would guess your comment is wrong (or pure guessing).

Comment: Not a *pure* guess https://developers.google.com/experts/people/paul-blundell . I can go get you a second opinion if you want? Maybe someone on the games team.

Comment: @Blundell what about second opinion? Are you sure! is it legal?

Comment: See this, it may help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24903674/can-google-play-games-service-be-used-for-non-games